# Induction on a circuit with switch

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering, induction

I have the following circuit:

[image]

It is subject to a steady, time-invariant magnetic field which points out of the paper. At $t = 0$, the switch closes.

I thought that the magnetic flux would decrease at the moment the switch closes and, by Faraday's law, cause the voltmeter to change its reading. However, my textbook says that the voltmeter won't change. How does one arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Note, Faraday's law is given as follows

$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\iint_{ }^{ }\vec{B}\cdot\vec{dA}$$.

Now you will get some current only if the right hand side is non-zero. As $\vec{B}$ is not changing only way you can get non-zero value at the right hand side is by changing area covered by any **closed circuit**.

Intially, your circuit was open, now you just close it. The open circuit didn't define any **closed area**. So, you can't think "closing the switch" as the change in the area by any closed-circuit. The moment, you close the switch completely you get the **closed circuit**. Now to get some current you either have to distort the circuit maintaining it as closed or have to switch off the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the right hand wire to the left to make the loop smaller, the charge carriers in the wire would experience a force (component of velocity perpendicular to magnetic field) which gives rise to an observed emf. If instead you keep the area constant and change the field, you get field lines crossing the conductor. Again there is relative motion between the charge carriers and the field lines and an induced emf.

But in this case the wire is stationary and the field lines are stationary. Therefore there is no force on the charge carriers and closing the switch will do nothing.

No fluctuation will be observed - and that has nothing to do with the (lack of) speed of response of the meter- there simply is no emf generated.

Answer (score -1):

According to faraday law, the electromotive Force is produced by changing magnetic flux. The emf remains as long as the magnetic flux is variable. Once the flux becomes constant the emf disappears.

In the above scenario there is a change in magnetic flux. This change is due to difference in the length of previous loop and present loop. The magnetic flux changes instantly and voltmeter cannot detect this change. An oscilloscope might detect the small change.

Instead of putting a switch put a rheostat and slowly change the resistance from maximum to minimum resistance. The voltmeter can detect the change in voltage.